# Emulate shading of a parameteric surface using Cairo graphics

Tags: graphics, cairo

A "cushion shaded" treemap is parametric surface that is a sum of parabolic curves. Each node in the tree (including internal nodes) is represented as a parabolic surface and the tree is rendered as the sum of all surfaces. The result is a nice sense of depth because the darkness between nodes is proportional to their height in the tree.

The [original paper](http://www.win.tue.nl/~vanwijk/ctm.pdf) [pdf] implements a simple raster rendering. I would like to render to a vector format to make my output scalable. *How do I emulate shading on a piece-wise quadratic surface using Cairo's gradient mesh?*

I think each shaded quad could be converted to four bezier-sided triangles with the curvature of the sides proportional to some ratio of the lighting angle and the surface normal, but I'm really not sure how to implement that transform.